# Issue with Angular Directive Usage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have a requirement like I will get an array of elements as an attribute to a directive, and based on the size of array objects  I have to iterate and create the template.Please find my JS class below.

```
mainApp.directive('student', function() {
    var directive = {};
    directive.restrict = 'E';
    directive.template = "Student: <b>{{student.name}}</b> , Roll No: <b>{{student.rollno}}</b>";

    directive.scope = {
        student : "=name"
    }

    directive.compile = function(element, attributes) {
       element.css("border", "1px solid #cccccc");

       var linkFunction = function($scope, element, attributes) {
            for (i = 0;i<$scope.student.length;i++){
               element.html("Student: <b>"+$scope.student[i].name +"</b> , Roll No: <b>"+$scope.student[i].rollno+"</b><br/>");
            }
        }

        return linkFunction;
     }

     return directive;
});
```

My data is like

```
$scope.students = [
    {
        name:"TestName1",
        rollno:2
    },
    {
        name:"TestName2",
        rollno:1
    }
];
```

And my html is like

```
<student name="students"></student><br/>
```

Also a working example is available in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/42lDUx1viF0nWLV0YsCI).

The issue is that the first student object is overwritten by the second one. Please let me know how can i correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `element.html` updates the html of the element. You are updating the content multiple times, the last update is what you finally see. Use `element.append`, to append your templates during the iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
mainApp.directive('student', function() {
    var directive = {};
    directive.restrict = 'E';
    directive.template = "Student: <b>{{student.name}}</b> , Roll No: <b>{{student.rollno}}</b>";

    directive.scope = {
        student : "=name"
    };

    directive.compile = function(element, attributes) {
        element.css("border", "1px solid #cccccc");

        var linkFunction = function($scope, element, attributes) {
            for (i = 0;i<$scope.student.length;i++){
                element.append("Student: <b>"+$scope.student[i].name +"</b> , Roll No: <b>"+$scope.student[i].rollno+"</b><br/>");
            }
        }

        return linkFunction;
    }

    return directive;
});
```

You have to use `element.append()` instead of `element.html()`